# HighCharts remove stack totals

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm creating a stacked bar chart just like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/edge/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/). Notice that the total of each stack is displayed at the top, how can I disable/hide this?

Comment: @Chris "StackLabels" isn't the most Descriptive name for a total sum label. I struggled to find this option (in code written by someone else), too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    },
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
        }
    }
},
```

you need to turn the stackLabels to false like in the example above

```
stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what if I wanted to just show the totals and hide the rest? Is this possible?

Comment: @Graph Do you mean, show only the totals at the top of the stack and hide the labels within the columns? If so, you would want to set `plotOptions.series.dataLabels` to `enabled: false`.

Comment: @MikeZavarello that is what I wanted, I can't try it right now but looks promising. Thank you very much!